# How can I block all outgoing Windows connection but allow connect to a specific IP address?

Tags: windows-firewall

I have a (Windows) server and have to block all outgoing connections but only allow connecting a software to a trusted IP address.

How can I do that?

I added a new rule in Windows firewall to block all programs, and then added a rule to allow connection the program to an IP, but second rule does not work.

Windows Firewall Configuration

> [image: Windows Firewall Configuration]

Connections Blocked

> [image: Connections Blocked]

Also I added a new rule that allows Chrome to access anywhere, but it does not works… Although the order of new rule is upper than old one!

Comment: @LPChip , thanks for your response, Although the new rule was higher than the previous one, I still added a _ to the beginning of its name, but it had no effect. I added the screenshots to the question.

Comment: @LPChip: Microsoft specifically says that there is no such ordering though, other than [all allow rules > all deny rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/network-security/windows-firewall/rules). It's not iptables.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Ah, I got the two mixed up.